# Fixing DNS leak - transparent proxy

Tags: proxy, dns

My ISP is using a transparent proxy to intercept my DNS lookup requests when using VPN. Is there a way to prevent that? *I am using Lubuntu if that makes any differance.*

Comment: Umm that's not good. I would be inclined to part company with that service provider.

Answer (score 2):

With a properly setup VPN all DNS traffic will be done through the VPN and cannot be intercepted. So you might check the configuration of your *unknown* VPN solution you use. Apart from that - how did you determine that your ISP is doing what you claim?

Comment: https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ only my ISP shows up. On other networks the VPN provider shows up (have tried on multiple networks and providers).

Comment: @Rectifier: which still leaves the question what kind of VPN you have and how did you configure it. BTW, some VPN don't handle environments properly where IPv6 is available, that is only IPv4 is sent through the VPN.  If you are in such environments it might be that DNS traffic, youtube etc is done with IPv6 and thus bypasses the VPN.

Comment: openvpn, I used the guide on the site of my vpn provider (ovpn [swedish]). Here is the solution for my problem on windows: https://dnsleaktest.com/how-to-fix-a-dns-leak.html. I dont know how to do this on ubuntu though.

Comment: @Rectifier: OpenVPN is one of the VPN solutions which seems to be affected by the IPv6 problem. But I don't know if this the relevant in your case since I don't know if you have IPv6 connectivity. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/440302/how-to-disable-ipv6-when-connecting-to-an-openvpn-server-using-network-manager-o

Answer (score 0):

DoT (DNS over TLS) or DoH (DNS over HTTPS) are common keywords nowadays, these big internet players such as [Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-tls/) or [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/doh/) already had their resolvers supported.

You can [set up](https://dnsprivacy.org/wiki/display/DP/DNS+Privacy+-+The+Solutions) your own servers/client while connecting via VPN to prevent this.